# App not responding(ANR) while turning OFF the screen suddenly in andriod ? How can i solve this in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm a flash(as3) developer. I'm getting many App not responding(ANR) messages from my app. Google Play console shows me this issue in ANR and Crashes section. Its due to  turning OFF the screen suddenly by pressing the power button or otherwise in sleep mode. How can I solve this ?

message from Google Play Console:
**Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50200010 (has extras) }**

Does anyone have clues to solve this problem ? Please help me.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Comment: @Yeti. Thanks for the reply. I have made some changes to my questions and updated it. Please verify. Also I have included the exact message from play console for your reference.